# Jquery Formbuilder checkbox issue

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formbuilder

i am using jquery formbuilder, there is drag and drop functionality in it. Firstly when i drag and drop the checkbox is auto selected and i have no control to deselect it. secondly, considering when i created the form the checkbox is autoselected, in the answer section, if i deselect the checkbox and when i try to edit it again, it is selected eventho it should be deselected.

1. I would want to deselect the checkbox in the first place when dragged and dropped.
2. The edit issue is persisting due to pint 1.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.